# Python Rank with non numeric columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to find a way to do nested ranking (row number) in python that is equivalent to the following in TSQL:
I have a table thank looks like this:

```
data = {
    'col1':[11,11,11,22,22,33,33],
    'col2':['a','b','c','a','b','a','b']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


# col1  col2 
# 11     a      
# 11     b  
# 11     c
# 22     a      
# 22     b      
# 33     a      
# 33     b
```

Looking for Python equivalent to:

```
SELECT
col1
,col2
,row_number() over(Partition by col1 order by col2) as rnk
FROM df
group by col1, col2
```

The output to be:

```
# col1  col2  rnk
# 11     a      1
# 11     b      2
# 11     c      3
# 22     a      1
# 22     b      2
# 33     a      1
# 33     b      2
```

I've tried to use `rank()` and `groupby()` but I keep running into a problem of `No numeric types to aggregate`. Is there a way to `rank` non numeric columns and give them row numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cumcount()

```
 df['rnk']=df.groupby('col1')['col2'].cumcount()+1



 col1 col2  rnk
0    11    a    1
1    11    b    2
2    11    c    3
3    22    a    1
4    22    b    2
5    33    a    1
6    33    b    2
```